# Use of slice to iterate a list

Tags: python

When I use slicing to iterate the list I get proper output.

Code:

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
for w in words[:]:
    if len(w) > 6:
        words.insert(0, w)

print(words)
```

Output:

```
['defenestrate', 'cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
```

But when I do not use a slice to iterate, the output goes into an infinite loop.

Code:

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
for w in words:
    if len(w) > 6:
        words.insert(0, w)

print(w)
```

Can anyone explain why such issue occurs?

Comment: Slices create copies.

Comment: `words[:]` creates a copy of the list, so you don't actually modify the list, as in your second example

Comment: As you have discovered, it is never a good idea to modify a list while you're iterating over it.

Answer (score 1):

That is because slicing creates a new object.

Here is how these codes work:

**The first one:**

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
for w in words[:]:
    if len(w) > 6:
        words.insert(0, w)

print(words)
```

At first `words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']`, When you do `for w in words[:]` it's like doing:

```
temp = words.copy()
for w in temp:
   ...
```

To understand what the second code is doing you can run this code:

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate'] 
for w in words: 
    print(words, w) 
    if len(w) > 6: 
        words.insert(0, w) 
    i += 1 
    if i == 15: break
```

Which will give you this output:

```
['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate'] cat
['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate'] window
['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate'] defenestrate
['defenestrate', 'cat', 'window', 'defenestrate'] defenestrate
['defenestrate', 'defenestrate', 'cat', 'window', 'defenestrate'] defenestrate
['defenestrate', 'defenestrate', 'defenestrate', 'cat', 'window', 'defenestrate'] defenestrate
.
.
.
```

After the third iteration the for loop sees that it has iterated up until the third element of the words array, then it goes to the forth element. Which is again `defenestrate` so it reads it and adds it to the beginning of the array so the array becomes of length five and the same thing will happen over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

This is because slicing creates a copy of the list before you iterate over it. When you insert into the list you are iterating over, you are adding more elements to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the first case, slicing have the effect of *fixing* the list you are looping to the original one.

In the second case, you continue to add new element to the list, so the cycle becomes without end.

Answer (score 0):

The slice returns a new list which is being iterated. Because there are only 3 items in the new list, the loop will iterate 3 times then terminate. In the second example you are iterating through `words` AND adding to it. Every time you add to your list it's one more item to iterate through. Here is some code to help you understand:

```py
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
count = 0
for w in words:
    print("Words: {}, Current word: {}".format(words, w))
    if len(w) > 6:
       words.insert(0, w)
    if count > 10: # This is just to break so we don't enter the infinite loop
       break
    count += 1
```

Notice how the list changes when you add a word and how that effects your iterating.